# How to apply styling to elements created with .insertAdjacentHtml method

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can't apply styling to elements created with `.insertAdjacentHTML`.

I've tried using `.style.cssText` but it doesn't work.

**JS:**

```
function addTime(){
    const newTimeSpan=document.createElement('span');
    const date=new Date();
    const currentTime=`${addZero(date.getHours())} : ${addZero(date.getMinutes())} : ${addZero(date.getSeconds())}`
    const newTimeSpanText=document.createTextNode(currentTime);
    newTimeSpan.appendChild(newTimeSpanText);
    newTimeSpan.style.cssText="border:solid 1px black;padding:2px;margin-right:10px;";
    const liItem=document.querySelector('li');
    liItem.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin',newTimeSpan.innerHTML)

}
addTime();
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="list-box">
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="item">item 1</li>
    <li class="item">item 2</li>
    <li class="item">item 3</li>
    <li class="item">item 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I was actually expecting to have a border around the `newTimeSpan.innerHtml` it doesn't appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `insertAdjacentElement` and insert the element, not its content.

```js
(function() {
  const newTimeSpan = document.createElement('span');
  const date = new Date();
  const currentTime = `${new Date().getHours()} : ${new Date().getMinutes()} : ${new Date().getSeconds()}`
  const newTimeSpanText = document.createTextNode(currentTime);
  newTimeSpan.appendChild(newTimeSpanText);
  newTimeSpan.style.cssText = "border:solid 1px black;padding:2px;margin-right:10px;";
  const liItem = document.querySelector('li');
  liItem.insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin', newTimeSpan);
})()
```

```html
<div class="list-box">
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="item">item 1</li>
    <li class="item">item 2</li>
    <li class="item">item 3</li>
    <li class="item">item 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This is even better than my solution. It's better to use elements than convert to/from HTML.

Comment: Its better in this use case.

Comment: @NidhinJoseph ty for the answer <3. when i use only newTimeSpan the document displays [object HTMLSpanElement] instead of currentTime

Comment: did you change to `insertAdjacentElement` ?

Comment: @NidhinJoseph ohh i didn't see that.thnx for pointing out and for your precious help!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're inserting `newTimeSpan.innerHTML`. That just returns the HTML inside the span, it doesn't return the span itself, and the styles are attributes of the span.

Use `newTimeSpan.outerHTML` instead of `newTimeSpan.innerHTML`, then it will return the HTML of the span, along with its stylying.

```js
function addTime() {
  const newTimeSpan = document.createElement('span');
  const date = new Date();
  const currentTime = `${addZero(date.getHours())} : ${addZero(date.getMinutes())} : ${addZero(date.getSeconds())}`
  const newTimeSpanText = document.createTextNode(currentTime);
  newTimeSpan.appendChild(newTimeSpanText);
  newTimeSpan.style.cssText = "border:solid 1px black;padding:2px;margin-right:10px;";
  const liItem = document.querySelector('li');
  liItem.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', newTimeSpan.outerHTML)

}
addTime();

function addZero(n) {
  return n < 10 ? "0" + n : n;
}
```

```html
<div class="list-box">
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="item">item 1</li>
    <li class="item">item 2</li>
    <li class="item">item 3</li>
    <li class="item">item 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: thnx for your help i eventually made it!

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is innerHTML instead of outerHTML:

```js
function addTime(){
    const newTimeSpan=document.createElement('span');
    // ...
    const newTimeSpanText=document.createTextNode('currentTime');
    newTimeSpan.appendChild(newTimeSpanText);
    newTimeSpan.style.cssText="border:solid 1px black;padding:2px;margin-right:10px;";    
    const liItem=document.querySelector('li');
    liItem.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin',newTimeSpan.outerHTML);
}

addTime();
```

```html
<div class="list-box">
    <ul class="list">
        <li class="item">item 1</li>
        <li class="item">item 2</li>
        <li class="item">item 3</li>
        <li class="item">item 4</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: ty for you time i finally did it <3

Answer (score 0):

### Complementary exemple on insertAdjacentElement as solution

Using `insertAdjacentElement` as already demonstrated by the other fellows is way to go. You can take a look in this project provided by [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement):

- [LIVE DEMO - adding colored boxes](https://mdn.github.io/dom-examples/insert-adjacent/insertAdjacentElement.html)
- [SOURCE CODE - Github](https://github.com/mdn/dom-examples/blob/master/insert-adjacent/insertAdjacentElement.html)

This DEMO really helped me out in the process of understanding this element.

---

Hope it helps you too!